# azure function V2 c# scipt - get entity from azure tables

Tags: azure

Good Morning
I have a question, why I did not use this code in azure function?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---c-script-example---one-entity 
They give me this error:`

> Funkce (dbC4/TimerTrigger1) Chyba: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error
>   indexing method 'Functions.TimerTrigger1'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'database' to type
>   Data. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If
>   you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus,
>   Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
>   extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(),
>   builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

`
please help me

here is the function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "databas",
      "tableName": "dbc",
      "partitionKey": "Test",
      "rowKey": "test3",
      "take": "50",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

here is run.cvsx:

```
using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, Data database, ILogger log)

{
log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

log.LogInformation($"Name in Database entity: {database.Name}");

}

public class Data
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test the table binding and it won't hit this error. So I check your code And I find a difference, it's your table binding name doesn't match the run.csx parameter name, one is `databas` and one is `database`. Then I change my binding name, then I reproduce your exception.

So the solution is just change them to the same name.

**function.json**

```
 {
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "myTimer",
          "type": "timerTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
        },

        {
          "name": "databas",
          "type": "table",
          "tableName": "Person",
          "partitionKey": "george",
          "rowKey": "chen",
          "take": "50",
          "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
          "direction": "in"
        }
      ]
    }
```

**run.csx**

```
using System;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log,Data database)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    log.LogInformation($"Name in Person entity: {database.Name}");
}
public class Data
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID {get;set;}
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jan Perdok,If this could work you could accept it as the answer to close it. And if you have a new question you could post it as a new case.